# Does anyone know what manga this is from?

Tags: story-identification, manga

This is the last page of chapter 25 it seems:

[image: Imaging a male-presenting warrior clutching a pillow and proclaiming that "Something's wrong .... It can't be."] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A reverse Google image search indicates it is *[Saikyou no Kurokishi, Sentou Maid ni Tenshoku shimashita](https://myanimelist.net/manga/112668/Saikyou_no_Kurokishi_Sentou_Maid_ni_Tenshoku_shimashita)*.

Summary from [the light novel entry](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/saikyou-no-kurokishi-sentou-maid-ni-tenshoku-shimashita-light-novel):

> Albright, who was famous as “the strongest Black Knight”, was reincarnated as a girl, Maria, whose ribbon suited her well for same reason. Maria, 16 years old, is currently a maid in the Marquess of Urband family in attendance to the Daughter of the Marquees, Relena. After Relena became engaged to the 4th Prince, the area around Maria had gotten busier…

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!